# How to get access to section element in nightwatch using at notation

Tags: javascript, webdriver, nightwatch.js

**Environment**

- nightwatch: ^0.9.21
- node: v9.11.1,
- chrome

**Where is a problem:**

*page-object:*

```
url: config.url,
sections: {
    dropdown: {
      selector: 'span[class="selection"]',
      elements: {
        inner: 'span[class="selection"] > span',
        list: 'ul[class="select2-results__options"]',
        first: 'ul[class="select2-results__options"] li:first-child',
        last: 'ul[class="select2-results__options"] li:last-child',
      },
    },
  },
```

Call

```
    const myPage = browser.page.mypage()
    const section = myPage.section.dropdown
    section.expect.element('@list').to.be.visible
```

What i expect:

> Expected element  to be visible
>   - condition was met in 29ms

What i get:

> Expected element  to be
>   visible - element was not found  - expected "visible" but got: "not
>   found"

Also, when I use click() it works but 'expect' does not return selector from '@list'

```
section
  .click('@list') <-- clicked
  .expect.element('@list').to.be.visible <- return 
 <Section[name=dropdown],Element[name=@list]> instead of selector
```

I have no problems to access any element inside page-object with '@' notation, but when I'm trying to get an element from section it fails.

P.S.: Sometimes an error msg is changed to

> Unable to locate element:
>   "Section[name=dropdown],Element[name=@thirdItem]" using: recursion